# Some brushes not working (Photoshop CC 2018)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, pencil

I'm starting to learn drawing in Photoshop with my Surface Pro and for some reason some brushes will just not draw. Basic brushes work, but in other categories like in dry brushes (sorry my brush names are in french for some reason so my translations may not be accurates) the Kyle ultimate brush does nothing while the Kyle ultimate carcoal works.

I can't see any reason why it would not work, i'm not a total newbie at photoshop, i've just never used it to draw. I have a color selected, i have no selection that would limit where i can draw on the screen, my layer is not locked... I'm totally lost.

Comment: what if you try the same brush with mouse?

Comment: Hi, absolutly nothing either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got it (totally by accident actually. It didn't work because my canvas was in 32 bits. Photoshop didn't say anything when i was trying to use the brush, but when i tried to fill the canvas using the fill tool Photoshop complained about 32 bits. Now all brushes work.

Answer (score -2):

Brush/pencil not operating in Photoshop. If a tool is not executing the means you anticipate, attempt resetting that tool by right-clicking on its' icon in the Options bar, and selecting "Reset Device" from the context menu. Also, examine your foreground/background shades at the end of the Tool kit. They need to be black/white.

Comment: This was not it at all, please see my answer above.

Comment: This answer is really confusing. There is no "reset device" option in the context menu, only "reset tool".  Also what does the colour of the foreground or background have to do with these tools not working?  There is absolutely no reason why you can't choose different colours with the Brush or Pencil tools.